# Google Play Console refuses SHA-1 key that Firebase Google signin requires

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-signin, google-play-console, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to replace a native Android app with a React Native app. I use the same `google-services.json`, the same keystore file, and the same `storeFile`, `storePassword`, `keyAlias`, and `keyPassword` to build my `app-release.aab`. However, my `GoogleSigninButton` from `@react-native-google-signin/google-signin` sign in doesn't work.

My keystore file has 2 certificates. If I use the alias of the other certificate, the `GoogleSigninButton` sign in succeeds. However, I get the error in the screenshot below if I try to create a release.

[image]

I saw on other answers that I'm supposed to add the SHA-1 to my Firebase Console Project Settings. However, I get this error in the screenshot below.

[image]

The SHA-1 of the other alias works for Google signin, even though I didn't add that SHA-1 to my Firebase Console Project Settings.

How can I troubleshoot this further?

I've already gone through my list of credentials in https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials and deleted all those I think are irrelevant.